# Reverse Reading List Order in Safari for iOS

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

I want to read through my reading list in the order that I add links, but making use of the seamless page to page scrolling functionality requires that I read them starting with the one I added most recently.

Is there a way to reverse this?